# Scrapy: How to load multiple items in separate function?

Tags: python, scrapy, items

I would like to do the processing and loading of items in a function separated from `parse_product` which is the `prepare_item_download()` function in my case. However, when I run my spider, I get the error message that it needs to return a Request, BaseItem, dict or None and not a generator. It works when I leave it in the `parse_product` function.

Here's my code:

```
from scrapy import Request, Spider
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from firmware.items import FirmwareItem
import re


class AvmSpider(Spider):
    name = 'avm'

    start_urls = [
        'http://download.avm.de/fritzbox/',
        'http://download.avm.de/fritzwlan/',
        'http://download.avm.de/fritzpowerline/'
    ]

    # parse top-level pages
    def parse(self, response):
        for product_url in self.link_extractor(response=response, prefix=('beta', 'tools', 'license', '..')):
            yield Request(url=product_url, callback=self.parse_product)

    # parse each product; call self as long as not in fritz.os directory
    def parse_product(self, response):
        path = response.request.url.split('/')[:-1]
        if path[-1] == 'fritz.os':
            yield self.prepare_item_download(response, path)
        else:
            for sub in self.link_extractor(response=response, prefix=('recover', '..')):
                yield Request(url=response.urljoin(sub), callback=self.parse_product)

    # get release dates, populate and load item 
    def prepare_item_download(self, response, path: str):
        release_dates = self.date_extractor(response)
        for index, file_url in enumerate(self.link_extractor(response=response, prefix='..')):
            if file_url.endswith('.image'):
                loader = ItemLoader(item=FirmwareItem(), selector=file_url)
                loader.add_value('file_urls', file_url)
                loader.add_value('vendor', 'avm')
                loader.add_value('device_name', path[-3])
                loader.add_value('device_class', path[-4])
                loader.add_value('release_date', release_dates[index])
                yield loader.load_item()
        yield None


    # return all links which do not start with a certain prefix
    @staticmethod
    def link_extractor(response, prefix) -> list:
        return [response.urljoin(p) for p in response.xpath('//a/@href').extract() if not p.startswith(prefix)]

    # return release dates of all images listed on current page
    @staticmethod
    def date_extractor(response) -> list:
        release_dates = list()
        for text in response.xpath('//pre/text()').extract():
            match = re.search(r'(\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2})', text)
            if match:
                release_dates.append(match.group(1))

        return release_dates
```

The above code does not work. Below you can see the working code:

```
    def parse_product(self, response):
        path = response.request.url.split('/')[:-1]
        if path[-1] == 'fritz.os':
            release_dates = self.date_extractor(response)
            for index, file_url in enumerate(self.link_extractor(response=response, prefix='..')):
                if file_url.endswith('.image'):
                    loader = ItemLoader(item=FirmwareItem(), selector=file_url)
                    loader.add_value('file_urls', file_url)
                    loader.add_value('vendor', 'avm')
                    loader.add_value('device_name', path[-3])
                    loader.add_value('device_class', path[-4])
                    loader.add_value('release_date', release_dates[index])
                    yield loader.load_item()
        else:
            for sub in self.link_extractor(response=response, prefix=('recover', '..')):
                yield Request(url=response.urljoin(sub), callback=self.parse_product)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `parse_product` function generates a *generator*:

```
def parse_product(self, response):
    path = response.request.url.split('/')[:-1]
    if path[-1] == 'fritz.os':
        yield self.prepare_item_download(response, path)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead you should use `yield from` statement to unpack the generator:

```
def parse_product(self, response):

    path = response.request.url.split('/')[:-1]
    if path[-1] == 'fritz.os':
        yield from self.prepare_item_download(response, path)
              ^^^^
        # or for python <3.3
        for item in self.prepare_item_download(response, path):
            yield item
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed. Did not know about the 'yield from' command.